# priority precedence between linux thread and process

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, scheduler

If i have two processes, having one thread each with priorities as below:

```
Process 1 - SCHED_FIFO - prio  10
    thread1  -  SCHED_FIFO - prio  20 
Process 2 - SCHED_FIFO - prio  15 
    thread2  -  SCHED_FIFO - prio  19
```

Now If both of them are ready to run at same time, which one would be picked, would it be based on thread priorities or process priorities?
I believe Linux kernel treats threads as processes so i am expecting thread 1 to get CPU, event though process 2 has higher priority than parent process of thread1.

Comment: *"Linux kernel treats threads as processes"* -- That's certainly true if you are using the older pthreads library.  Perhaps you should mention which kernel version, scheduler and threads library you are using.

Comment: Kernel is 2.6.18 and pthread lib that comes with it.